# Why Bounding Box Search executes too long?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, geospatial, geohashing

I'm using [GeoModel](http://code.google.com/p/geomodel/) to do Bounding Box Search. There are about 350 events in datastore but it executes >5 sec. The same results on my development environment and on google app engine. Why so long ? Do I need to add some Indexes ?

```
results = Event.bounding_box_fetch(
    Event.all(),
    geotypes.Box(north_east_lat, north_east_lng, south_west_lat, south_west_lng),
    max_results=100)
```

On this [example](http://geomodel-demo.appspot.com/) it works much better. 
I'm using Python 2.7 and google app engine

[image: appstat]
[image: appstat timeline]

Comment: can you enable [appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) and post the results?

Comment: I have attached print-screen. If there could be additional information to resolve this issue just let me know.

Comment: 350 results returned, or 350 in the datastore?

Comment: 350 in datastore. 100 is max results to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoModel is sort of "old stuff" now. It became to expensive since the new GAE Billing has taken place. There's no "official" alternative (from Google) from what I've seen.

Here's a detailed discussion on App Engine group. You might wanna check it out:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/-FqljlTruK4/aXrzUPAlNbAJ